# Ambiguous Input Redirect Java

Tags: java, linux, input, io-redirection

On Fedora 28 I'm trying to redirect from Standard Input a .txt file saved in the same folder of my java program;  I wrote in terminal

```
cd folderPath
java ClassName < `FileName.txt`
```

but I got this message

```
bash: FileName.txt: command not found...
bash: `FileName.txt`: ambiguos redirection
```

where I'm wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong quote:

```
java ClassName < `FileName.txt`
```

The ` will evaluate to a shell subcommand, whose name is `FileName.txt`.

What you want is single or double quote:

```
java ClassName < 'FileName.txt' # 1
java ClassName < "FileName.txt" # 2
java ClassName < FileName.txt   # 3
```

1. Single quote disallow expansion (eg: no `'${FILE}'`)
2. Double quote allow expansion (eg:  `"${FILE}"` resolve to `foobar` if `export FILE=foobar`)
3. Quote are not needed when the path does not contains specific characters, such as space.

Comment: It works with all three syntax! Solved!